# change of variable in ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to transform this equation in which r is differentiated with respect to t to $\theta$:

$m\ddot{r} - \frac{l^2}{mr^3} = f(r)$

to an equation $r(\theta)$

where

$mr^2 \dot{\theta} = l$

I derived from the chain rule the corresponing relation between derivatives with respect to t and $\theta$ which is

$\frac{d}{dt} = \frac{l}{mr^2}\frac{d}{d\theta}$

by substituting this into the first equation I get:

$\frac{l}{r^2}\frac{d}{d\theta}\left (\frac{l}{mr^2}\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right) -\frac{l^2}{mr^3} = f(r)$

by applying the substitution $u=1/r$ I get

$lu^2\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\frac{lu^2}{m}\frac{d}{d\theta} 1/u \right) -\frac{l^2u^3}{m} = f(r)$

and by the Quotient rule

$-\frac{u^2l^2}{m}\frac{d^2u}{d\theta^2}-\frac{l^2u^3}{m} = f(r)$

My manual yields this result

$\frac{d^2u}{d\theta^2} + u = -\frac{m}{l^2}\frac{d}{du}V \left (\frac{1}{u}\right)$

using the relation $f(r) =-\delta V /\delta r$

I don't know how to get it.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is something wrong with your second order derivative term. Note that:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d}{dt} = \frac{d\theta}{dt}\frac{d}{d\theta} \quad \mbox{and} \quad \frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}} = \frac{d\theta}{dt}\frac{d}{d\theta}\bigg{[}\frac{l}{mr^{2}}\frac{d}{d\theta}\bigg{]} \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{eqnarray}
Thus, we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d^{2}r}{dt^{2}}= \frac{l}{mr^{2}}\bigg{[}\frac{l}{mr^{2}}\frac{d^{2}r}{d\theta^{2}}-\frac{2l}{mr^{3}}\bigg{(}\frac{dr}{d\theta}\bigg{)}^{2}\bigg{]} \equiv \frac{l^{2}}{m^{2}r^{2}}\bigg{[}\frac{1}{r^{2}}\frac{d^{2}r}{d\theta^{2}}-\frac{2}{r^{3}}\bigg{(}\frac{dr}{d\theta}\bigg{)}^{2}\bigg{]} \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{eqnarray}

Now, if $u = 1/r$ then:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{du}{dr} = -\frac{1}{r^{2}}\frac{dr}{d\theta} \quad \mbox{and} \quad \frac{d^{2}u}{d\theta^{2}} = \frac{2}{r^{3}}\bigg{(}\frac{dr}{d\theta}\bigg{)}^{2}-\frac{1}{r^{2}}\frac{d^{2}r}{d\theta^{2}}\tag{3}\label{3}
\end{eqnarray}
Now, for the $f$ term, you have:
\begin{eqnarray}
f(r) = -\frac{dV}{dr} = \frac{du}{dr}\frac{dV}{du}= -\frac{1}{r^{2}}\frac{dV}{du} = -u^{2}V\bigg{(}\frac{1}{u}\bigg{)} \tag{4}\label{4}
\end{eqnarray}
Putting (\ref{2}), (\ref{3}) and (\ref{4}) together in your equation, we get:
\begin{eqnarray}
-\frac{l^{2}}{m}u^{2}\frac{d^{2}u}{d\theta^{2}}-\frac{l^{2}}{m}u^{3} = u^{2}\frac{dV}{du}\bigg{(}\frac{1}{u}\bigg{)} \tag{5}\label{5}
\end{eqnarray}
And, because we're assuming $u\neq 0$, we finally have:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d^{2}u}{d\theta^{2}}+ u = - \frac{m}{l^{2}}\frac{dV}{du}\bigg{(}\frac{1}{u}\bigg{)}
\end{eqnarray}